# Finding these three algorithm's run time

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, proof

Hi I am having a tough time showing the run time of these three algorithms for T(n). Assumptions include T(0)=0.

1) This one i know is close to Fibonacci so i know it's close to O(n) time but having trouble showing that:
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) +1

2) This on i am stumped on but think it's roughly about O(log log n):
T(n) = T([sqrt(n)]) + n. n greater-than-or-equal to 1. sqrt(n) is lower bound.

3)  i believe this one is in roughly O(n*log log n):
T(n) =  2T(n/2) + (n/(log n)) + n.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question--a clear statement of the order of `T(n)` or proof of that order? And what have you tried? Have you tried calculating `T(n)` for 20 or so values of `n` and checking your assumptions?

Comment: Hints for each question: 1) you are confused between the computational time complexity and growth rate complexity of Fibonacci; 2) repeatedly expand this and treat the result as you would with normal O-notation; 3) The summation over `n/log n` can be approximated with an integral - and the approximation turns out to be very good in the asymptotic case

Answer (score 0):

> T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + 1

Assuming T(0) = 0 and T(1) = a, for some constant a, we notice that T(n) - T(n-1) = T(n-2) + 1. That is, the growth rate of the function is given by the function itself, which suggests this function has exponential growth.

Let T'(n) = T(n) + 1. Then T'(n) = T'(n-1) + T'(n-2), by the above recurrence relation, and we have eliminated the troublesome constant term. T(n) and U(n) differ by a constant factor of 1, so assuming they are both non-decreasing (they are) then they will have the same asymptotic complexity, albeit for different constants n0.

To show T'(n) has asymptotic growth of O(b^n), we would need some base cases, then the hypothesis that the condition holds for all n up to, say, k - 1, and then we'd need to show it for k, that is, c*b^(n-2) + c*b^(n-1) < c*b^n. We can divide through by c*b^(n-2) to simplify this to 1 + b <= b^2. Rearranging, we get b^2 - b - 1 > 0; roots are (1 +- sqrt(5))/2, and we must discard the negative one since we cannot use a negative number as the base for our exponent. So for b >= (1+sqrt(5))/2, T'(n) may be O(b^n). A similar thought experiment will show that for b <= (1+sqrt(5))/2, T'(n) may be Omega(b^n). Thus, for b = (1+sqrt(5))/2 only, T'(n) may be Theta(b^n).

Completing the proof by induction that T(n) = O(b^n) is left as an exercise.

> T(n) = T([sqrt(n)]) + n

Obviously, T(n) is at least linear, assuming the boundary conditions require T(n) be nonnegative. We might guess that T(n) is Theta(n) and try to prove it. Base case: let T(0) = a and T(1) = b. Then T(2) = b + 2 and T(4) = b + 6. In both cases, a choice of c >= 1.5 will work to make T(n) < cn. Suppose that whatever our fixed value of c is works for all n up to and including k. We must show that T([sqrt(k+1)]) + (k+1) <= c*(k+1). We know that T([sqrt(k+1)]) <= c*sqrt(k+1) from the induction hypothesis. So T([sqrt(k+1)]) + (k+1) <= c*sqrt(k+1) + (k+1), and c*sqrt(k+1) + (k+1) <= c*(k+1) can be rewritten as cx + x^2 <= cx^2 (with x = sqrt(k+1)); dividing through by x (OK since k > 1) we get c + x <= cx, and solving this for c we get c >= x/(x-1) = sqrt(k+1)/(sqrt(k+1)-1). This eventually approaches 1, so for large enough n, any constant c > 1 will work.

Making this proof totally rigorous by fixing the following points is left as an exercise:

1. making sure enough base cases are proven so that all assumptions hold
2. distinguishing the cases where (a) k + 1 is a perfect square (hence [sqrt(k+1)] = sqrt(k+1)) and (b) k + 1 is not a perfect square (hence sqrt(k+1) - 1 < [sqrt(k+1)] < sqrt(k+1)).

> T(n) = 2T(n/2) + (n/(log n)) + n

This T(n) > 2T(n/2) + n, which we know is the recursion relation for the runtime of Mergesort, which by the Master theorem is O(n log n), s we know our complexity is no less than that.

Indeed, by the master theorem: T(n) = 2T(n/2) + (n/(log n)) + n = 2T(n/2) + n(1 + 1/(log n)), so

- a = 2
- b = 2
- f(n) = n(1 + 1/(log n)) is O(n) (for n>2, it's always less than 2n)
- f(n) = O(n) = O(n^log_2(2) * log^0 n)

We're in case 2 of the Master Theorem still, so the asymptotic bound is the same as for Mergesort, Theta(n log n).